# Upload file to AWS S3 using REST API Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve a file from the user's file system and upload it to AWS S3. However, I have had no success thus far doing so. To be more specific, I have been working with trying to upload images. So far the images won't render properly whenever I upload them. I am really only familiar with uploading images as Blobs, but since SHA256 function can't read a Blob I'm unsure what to do. Below is my code:

```
var grabFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
grabFile.open("GET", 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+bucketName+'/asd.jpeg', true);
grabFile.responseType = "arraybuffer";

grabFile.onload = function( e ) {
    var grabbedFile = this.response;
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );

    var base64data = '';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        //var readData = reader.result;
        var readData = blob;
        //readData = readData.split(',').pop();
        console.log(readData);
        console.log(readData.toString());
        var shaString = CryptoJS.SHA256(readData.toString()).toString();

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var signingKey = getSigningKey(dateStamp, secretKey, regionName, serviceName);
        var headersList = "content-type;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date";
        var time = new Date();

        time = time.toISOString();
        time = time.replace(/:/g, '').replace(/-/g,'');
        time = time.substring(0,time.indexOf('.'))+"Z";

        var canonString = "PUT\n"+
                            "/asd5.jpeg\n"+
                            "\n"+
                            //"content-encoding:base64\n"+
                            "content-type:image/jpeg\n"+
                            "host:"+bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com\n"+
                            'x-amz-acl:public-read\n'+
                            'x-amz-content-sha256:'+shaString+"\n"+
                            'x-amz-date:'+time+'\n'+
                            '\n'+
                            headersList+'\n'+
                            shaString;

        var stringToSign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n"+
                            time+"\n"+
                            dateStamp+"/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n"+
                            CryptoJS.SHA256(canonString);

        var authString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey).toString();
        var auth = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 "+
                    "Credential="+accessKey+"/"+dateStamp+"/"+regionName+"/"+serviceName+"/aws4_request, "+
                    "SignedHeaders="+headersList+", "+
                    "Signature="+authString;

        request.open("PUT", "https://"+bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com/asd5.jpeg", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
        //request.setRequestHeader("content-encoding", "base64");
        request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg");
        request.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
        request.setRequestHeader("x-amz-content-sha256", shaString);
        request.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", time);
        request.send(readData.toString());
        console.log(request);
```

How do I go about doing this? The code above just uploads something that's just a few Bytes because blob.toString() comes out as [Object Blob] and that's what gets uploaded. If I don't toString() it, I get an error from my SHA256 function.

As you can see, I tried reading it as Base64 before uploading it, but that did not resolve my problem either. This problem has been bugging me for close to a week now and I would love to get this solved. I've tried changing content-type, changed the body of what I'm uploading, etc. but nothing has worked.

EDIT: Forgot to mention (even though the title should imply it) but I cannot use the SDK for this. I was using it at one point, and with it I was able to upload images as Blobs. So I know this is possible, it's just that I don't know what crafty thing the SDK is doing to upload it.

EDIT2: I found the solution just in case someone stumbles across this in the future. Try setting replace every place I have shaString with 'UNSIGNED PAYLOAD' and send the blob and it will work! Here's where I found it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

Comment: Unrelated to your upload problem, it's generally not advisable for a web page to include AWS credentials, particularly the secret key. How are you populating the credentials?

Comment: Right now, for testing purposes, they are stored on the page. They'll be stored and pulled from somewhere else later once I get closer to completion. However, right now my main goal is to finish development on functionality.